# Problems with programming google play services plugin for unity

Tags: android, eclipse, plugins, unity-game-engine, google-play-services

While trying to construct my first game-app i've run into some problems that exceed my knowledge of programming.

I use Unity for making my game and have made a working admob plugin with eclipse for using in unity. I followed [this](http://fastegggames.com/blog/2014/3/16/tutorial-google-play-ads-with-admob-in-unity) tutorial to do so.

No problems so far, and with my new knowledge about making a plugin for unity i decided to make a second plugin based on the tutorial of google found [here](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/init).

However, for my plugin to work, i must not "extend" the class of the plugin. This confuses me because if i don't use "extends" i won't have the onCreate, onActivityResult, etc. Callbacks.

I know there must be a way to make this work, but my knowledge of java is too little to crack this problem.

I've tried all kinds of things to at least get the code to compile, but basically i'm just swinging in the dark here.

I've got this far with my code, needless to say it just makes my game crash when i call Test():

```
package google.signin;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.*;
import com.google.example.games.basegameutils.GameHelper;
import com.google.example.games.basegameutils.GameHelper.GameHelperListener;
import com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;

public class SignIn {

    private Activity activity; //Store the android main activity

    private GameHelper mHelper;

    public SignIn()
    {
        activity = UnityPlayer.currentActivity;


        activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run(){

                Activity subactivity = new Activity() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

                        // create game helper with all APIs (Games, Plus, AppState):
                        mHelper = new GameHelper(this, GameHelper.CLIENT_ALL);

                        GameHelperListener listener = new GameHelper.GameHelperListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSignInSucceeded() {
                                // handle sign-in success
                            }
                            @Override
                            public void onSignInFailed() {
                                // handle sign-in failure (e.g. show Sign In button)
                            }

                        };
                        mHelper.setup(listener);
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void onStart() {
                        super.onStart();
                        mHelper.onStart(this);
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void onStop() {
                        super.onStop();
                        mHelper.onStop();
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void onActivityResult(int request, int response, Intent data) {
                        super.onActivityResult(request, response, data);
                        mHelper.onActivityResult(request, response, data);
                    }
                };
            }
        });
    }

    public void Test()
    {
        activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run(){

                mHelper.beginUserInitiatedSignIn();

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Logcat says this is the problem:

```
07-14 11:19:10.786: E/AndroidRuntime(31262): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-14 11:19:10.786: E/AndroidRuntime(31262): Process: com.ChocolatePinecone.PrincessRescueRun, PID: 31262
07-14 11:19:10.786: E/AndroidRuntime(31262): java.lang.Error: FATAL EXCEPTION [main]
07-14 11:19:10.786: E/AndroidRuntime(31262): Unity version     : 4.3.4f1
07-14 11:19:10.786: E/AndroidRuntime(31262): Device model      : samsung GT-I9505
07-14 11:19:10.786: E/AndroidRuntime(31262): Device fingerprint: samsung/jfltexx/jflte:4.4.2/KOT49H/I9505XXUGNF1:user/release-keys
07-14 11:19:10.786: E/AndroidRuntime(31262): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-14 11:19:10.786: E/AndroidRuntime(31262):    at google.signin.SignIn$2.run(SignIn.java:78)
07-14 11:19:10.786: E/AndroidRuntime(31262):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
07-14 11:19:10.786: E/AndroidRuntime(31262):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
07-14 11:19:10.786: E/AndroidRuntime(31262):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
07-14 11:19:10.786: E/AndroidRuntime(31262):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
07-14 11:19:10.786: E/AndroidRuntime(31262):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-14 11:19:10.786: E/AndroidRuntime(31262):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-14 11:19:10.786: E/AndroidRuntime(31262):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
07-14 11:19:10.786: E/AndroidRuntime(31262):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
07-14 11:19:10.786: E/AndroidRuntime(31262):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I think it crashes because onStart and all that stuff from the subactivity is not being called. 
I have no idea if what i'm doing here is even in the right direction of solving this. Before i proceed taking swings i was hoping someone here could enlighten me, or at least give me some pointers of where to go...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever your mHelper object is, you haven't created it from what I can see. I've never used the class before so I have no idea if the declaration is right but an example

```
mHelper = new GameHelper();
```

Comment: In the onCreate function of subactivity i created it: mHelper = new GameHelper(this, GameHelper.CLIENT_ALL);

Comment: And that definitely gets called? Put some debug messages in there to make sure. I presume mHelper.beginUserInitialitedSignIn() is line 78 as well?

Comment: mHelper.beginUserInitialitedSignIn() is indeed line 78. The subactivity lifecycle (onCreate, onStart, etc.) Is not being called at all. Perhaps i have to use startActivity(intent), but i don't know how to succesfully implement this in my code.

Comment: Which makes sense because your class is not an activity. And as you mentioned you don't wish it to be an activity but I'll be interested to hear why you can't do that? You can have multiple activities in one project.

Comment: To succesfully implement my code in unity the class may not extend to anything. As soon as i extend my class to activity for example, all calls from unity to the class stop working.
I'm basing my plugin on the tutorial [here](http://fastegggames.com/blog/2014/3/16/tutorial-google-play-ads-with-admob-in-unity).

Comment: That shouldn't be the case. You'll need to add the newly created activity to the AndroidManifest.xml but I've successfully implemented plugins with their own activity. Or you can even override Unity's own Activity and add the behavior you want. If you really find that to be the case then you can probably just split your functions you've marked with @override into separate functions and have your unity code call each of them when required, i.e call oncreate when unity starts and so on.

Comment: See http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PluginsForAndroid.html to see how to extend Unity's own activity (should you wish to).

Comment: Perhaps i should indeed override unity's activity. Since my admob plugin does not override unity's activity, this new plugin should be able to coexist. I think i'll start over again based on [this tutorial](http://www.codestalkers.com/blog/android-plugins).
Thanks for your help!

Comment: No worries, do ask if you end up having further issues.

Comment: I've followed [this tutorial](http://www.lorenzonuvoletta.com/how-to-create-a-native-android-plugin-for-unity/) to the letter, but my app crashes at start with an "class not found" exception. As if the created jar file in the plugins folder does not have any class in it.

Comment: Have you added you're overridden activity to the AndroidManifest? And I presume you've named everything the same as the tutorial?

Comment: I seem to notice as well the example has a manifest and has this line <activity android:name=".UnityBridge". Now Whenever I've declared android:name elements, I've always had to do com.packagename.classname (essentially copying your package on line one of your android class and then adding your classname at the end). Might be worth doing the same with your's so it would be com.hello.world.UnityBridge

Comment: Yup! That seemed to be the problem. I now have a working plugin that just prints something on logcat. Now i only have to add the gamehelper code which should be no problem since i now have all the needed callbacks! Thanks again for all the help!

Comment: No worries! Welcome to the pain of Android development!